# Get upload URL by blog ID in multisite

Tags: multisite, attachments, uploads

The essence of the question is, I'm looking for a solution like this:

```
$blog_upload_dir_info = wp_upload_dir( $date, $blog_ID );
$blog_upload_url = $blog_upload_dir_info[ 'baseurl' ];
```

Where `$blog_ID` is different of the current blog ID. The most »WP-obvious« solution fails:

```
switch_to_blog( $blog_ID );
$blog_upload_dir_info = wp_upload_dir();
restore_current_blog();
```

as [wp_upload_dir()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cb1ad98015ea8e75474e22c39d77e4aaf3d008ab/wp-includes/functions.php#L1722) relies on the constant `WP_CONTENT_URL` which is dynamically set the URL of the current blog unless the option `upload_url_path` is set.

Of course, I could set this option, but this would couple my code to concrete system settings which includes much »WTF?«-potential.

So I decided to add this option virtually:

```
/**
 * Apply a value to the option blog_upload_url 
 * if there's not already one 
 *
 * @wp-hook option_upload_url_path
 * @param string $upload_url
 * @return string
 */
function get_real_blog_upload_url( $upload_url ) {

    if ( '' !== trim( $upload_url ) )
        return $upload_url;

    $upload_path = trim( get_option( 'upload_path' ) );
    $siteurl = get_option( 'siteurl' );
    $wp_content_dir = $siteurl . '/wp-content';

    if ( empty( $upload_path ) || 'wp-content/uploads' == $upload_path ) {
        $dir = $wp_content_dir . '/uploads';
    } elseif ( 0 !== strpos( $upload_path, ABSPATH ) ) {
        // $dir is absolute, $upload_path is (maybe) relative to ABSPATH
        $dir = path_join( ABSPATH, $upload_path );
    } else {
        $dir = $upload_path;
    }

    if ( empty( $upload_path ) || ( 'wp-content/uploads' == $upload_path ) || ( $upload_path == $dir ) )
        $upload_path = $wp_content_dir . '/uploads';
    else
        $upload_path = trailingslashit( $siteurl ) . $upload_path;


    return $upload_path;
}
```

which is in fact a partly fork of `wp_upload_dir()` and as such relies on constants which [isn't a good practice at all](http://wpkrauts.com/2015/the-guide-to-wordpress-path-and-urls/). Moreover a fork is always coupled to the original implementation and if the original changes, one also have to fix the fork.

So as this solution is far away from being perfect, I wonder if there's a better way to get upload URLs by blog IDs.

Comment: There's another workaround for this problem in the Plugin Multilingual Press: https://github.com/inpsyde/multilingual-press/blob/c6fb9a8d73e35d200a64f816bf135a12682cece5/inc/copy-site/Mlp_Copy_Attachments.php#L115

Comment: I think it is helpful that you add the source as answer for other readers. The link is not stable and outside the WPSE Answer.

Comment: @bueltge Basically I agree. But my comment relying to this workaround was a bit overhasty. The solution is an approach for this problem, but it has some limitations: https://github.com/inpsyde/multilingual-press/issues/133

When we found a solution, I of course will answer it here too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `get_option('upload_path')` after your `switch_to_blog( $blog_ID );`?
Does that do it?

Comment: (Build the full URL by using `get_blog_details` https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_details)

Comment: Look into `wp_upload_dir()`: The option `upload_path` is not a default option and might be empty. Further it could be omitted by the option `upload_url_path`. However, a proper solution for this problem would be to fork `wp_upload_dir()` completely to cover all this possible settings and edge cases.

Answer (score -1):

For completeness' sake, [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25650#comment:6) solution seems to work until the issue is fixed in core:

```
add_action('switch_blog', function($new_blog, $prev_blog_id) {
    update_option( 'upload_url_path',  get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/uploads');
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Yes, that should work in standard WordPress installs. However, I wouldn't want to use this due to the DB write action. This will make `switch_to_blog()` even slower.

Comment: This is also assuming that your content url is actually wp-content/uploads, which may not be the case.